# Will Service concept work even if App crash in Android?

Tags: android, android-service

I am working on an application for collecting crash reports in application, so that I have created class which extends Application for handling uncaught exception and created service class for communicate with server. 
I made a simple divide by zero exception in a button click and it produce exception but my service class does not called. I am sure have registered the service class in manifest file.

**my question is Will Service concept work even if application is crashed (force close) in Android?**

code:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    public void onCreate() {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) {
                handleUncaughtException(thread, e);
            }
        });
    }
    public void handleUncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Intent i = new Intent(MyApp.this, ServiceClass.class);
        startService(i);
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
public class ServiceClass extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("onStartCommand", "onStartCommand  called");
        // server communication code.
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Manifest xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ex.errorhandle"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name="com.ex.errorhandle.MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.ex.errorhandle.ServiceClass" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Why has downvotes? its really interesting to me to have an answer to this.